# iOS 15 focus mode development

Tags: ios

We can set up a focus status with customized turning on time and turning off time. I'd like to be notified when I am in my own app. Unfortunately INShareFocusStatusIntentHandling was not called when a system notification "Focus on" came out. Anybody know some solutions or ideas about it. Thanks ahead!

Comment: I think people will need a minimal reproducible example to be able to help you here

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'll try my best to describe it more in detail. On iOS 15 devices when we set one kind of focus status, we can specify when it is active and when it is inactive. However I didn't find any api to let me know the active time or the inactive time. As a result, there's no methods for me to know whether my device is focus active now. That is my question. I think there're some more experienced friends have a knowledge about that.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682143 you need to implement an Intents Extension from your app and have that extension share the results to the main app via UserDefaults or some other method. You cannot observe the focus state changes directly in your app.